# Table ant d expand able row icon

Tags: row, expand, antd

Here is the sand box link:
[Ant d expandable icon](https://codesandbox.io/s/6x60rqo4jr)

Is this possible to set width, height of expandable icon column (+ sign) or is it possible to render custom icon? Basically I want to  control the spacing between expandable column and "Name" column.

Answer (score 0):

You can now add

```
expandIcon={record => <i>expand</i>}
```

below the expandedRowRender line in the props. So it will look like :

```
<Table
columns={columns}
expandedRowRender={record => <p style={{ margin: 0 }}>{record.description}</p>}
expandIcon={record => <i>expand</i>}
dataSource={data}
/>
```

P.S. This only customizes the expand icon as you have asked, you'll have to write some more lines of code to make the *new icon* clickable and pass the record to show data in the expanded area.

Please give it a try and let me know if you need help with the onClick() part of it!

Answer (score 0):

I know it's too late, but it might help some new comer.

```
<Table
        size="small"
        dataSource={getDataSource()}
        locale={{ emptyText: "No Data found" }}
        expandedRowRender={expandedRowRender}
        expandIcon={record => showExpandIcon(record)}
        columns={getColumn()}
      />
```

Now inside your **showExpandIcon** custom function you can return whatever custom Icon you want.

```
showExpandIcon(record){
    const { expanded, onExpand } = record;
    if(expanded){
        return <CustomIcon onClick={e=>{onExpand(record, e)}}/>
    }
    else{
        return <SomeOtherCustomIcon onClick={e=>{onExpand(record, e)}}
    }
```

**onExpand** is an event, which you need to pass on onClick of your custom Icon to expand the row.

Answer (score 0):

try adding

```
expandIcon={record => <i>expand</i>}
```

below the **expandedRowRender** line in the props. So it will look like :

// like this we can add inside table props

```
 <Table
   ...props
    **expandedRowRender={record => <p style={{ margin: 0 }}>}**
    />
```

Comment: Please provide a detailed explanation to your answer, in order for the next user to understand your answer better.